# How to SELECT from an unnested hardcoded array in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I use SQLalchemy to compile queries for BigQuery. Now I want to make a CTE for the following SQL:

```
SELECT * from unnest([0, 1, 5, 10, 25, 50]) as classification
```

But I cannot figure out how to do this in SQLalchemy. I've tried

```
q = db.session.query(func.unnest([0, 1, 5, 10, 25, 50]).label("classification"))).cte()
```

and

```
q = db.session.query(literal("* from unnest([0, 1, 5, 10, 25, 50]) as classification")).cte()
```

But neither of those give me right compiled results when I join this CTE into another `q`.

To elaborate on the final goal here: I want to make this hardcoded array into a CTE as I have another query that calculates the count for each `classification`. I want to `LEFT JOIN` this unnesting q, so that if a `classification` has no count, the `LEFT JOIN` will make sure there is still a row (with count 0) for the classification.

Answer (score 1):

I have for now managed to fix this using the following code:

```
classification_qs = []
for item in [0, 1, 5, 10, 25, 50]:
    classification_qs.append(db.session.query(literal(item).label("classification")))
q = union_all(*classification_qs).cte()
```

Instead of trying to unnest an array, we make multiple queries for a single value and then union them together.